# Greater than key doesn't work on new keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I'm having trouble with a keyboard I received as a gift (i.e. I can't return it).

I'm trying to use the greater than key, but it doesn't seem to work.
I can type the "." but when I hit shift+"." it produces nothing.
So, the key is working (or else "." wouldn't show up), and the shift key is working.  It's supposedly plug and play, so is this a driver issue?
Any ideas on what else I can do to try and fix it?

GC-700 LUMEN

Model number: DS-2471+ET8109

Comment: Are there any other shift-modified keys (like < or : or @) that don't work? This seems very peculiar and seems like a software issue to me. Try to use the on screen keyboard (if Windows, hold `win` and press `r` to get the run box, and type `osk` and hit Enter.) Try to make the key in that case and see if it works.

Comment: The only other key that doesn't work (that I've found) is shift+6.  I've used the osk and both produce the symbol when clicked on.

Comment: I see, i don't think that any software is grabbing those inputs then. I'm guessing the previous keyboard worked properly, so I would gather that it's a driver issue. Try and get the VID and PID of the device by going to device manager -> input devices. Then you can google the VID and PID to find any alternative drivers, and possibly other people who've had issues with it. There may be a software for the keyboard, like Logitech have for their macros.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can figure out how to do that